# SQL joining between columns and rows

Tags: sql

I have two tables with the following formats:

Table Name: "Awards"

```
id  |    Name   |   Exp_1   |   Exp_2   |   Exp_3
1   |    Joe    |   1       |   2       |   3
2   |    Bob    |   1       |           |   3
3   |    James  |           |   2       |
```

Table Name: "Exp"

```
id  |    Exp          
1   |    Service       
2   |    Integrity      
3   |    Timeliness
```

The result table I need to create:

```
id  |    Name   |   Exp_1_val   |   Exp_2_val     |   Exp_3_val
1   |    Joe    |   Service     |   Integrity     |   Timeliness
2   |    Bob    |   Service     |                 |   Timeliness
3   |    James  |               |   Integrity     |
```

So basically if one of the "Exp_" columns in my Awards table is not null, I need it's corresponding value from Exp table.  But I can't match these with ID numbers, only their values.  Is there a type of join can do accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to need multiple left joins:

```
select a.id, a.name, e1.exp as exp1, e2.exp as exp2, e3.exp as exp3
from awards a left join
     exp e1
     on a.exp_1 = e1.id left join
     exp e2
     on a.exp_2 = e2.id left join
     exp e3
     on a.exp_3 = e3.id ;
```

Comment: That's the answer in the question that lad2025 linked.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff and ArturoAP Thank you both for your responses.  I marked this as the answer since it was submitted first.  I wasn't sure if I could use a left join in this case since I'm still learning.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.id, a.Name, exp1.Exp, exp2.Exp, exp3.Exp FROM Awards a
LEFT JOIN Exp exp1 on exp1.id = a.Exp_1
LEFT JOIN Exp exp2 on exp2.id = a.Exp_2
LEFT JOIN Exp exp3 on exp3.id = a.Exp_3
```

You will need to join each of your Exp fields in Awards table to the Exp table,
use LEFT JOIN in case there is no value to link them with.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a left join in order to bring the two tables together. See the chart below to help you understand it. From Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

[image]

Comment: If you copied that from somewhere you need to attribute it.